# How to send a file via FTP in android adb shell?

Tags: android, ftp, adb, ftp-client, busybox

How to send a file via FTP in android adb shell ?
I have installed busybox. I want to recieve a file from a FTP server in adb shell.These much of commands are supporting.
Somebody please help..?

Comment: from adb connected to your computer then to your phone, like this:

ftp -> computer -> phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the busybox commands for ftp are ftpget/ftpput. On my cyanogenmod Android 2.3.3 system sits Busybox v1.19.1, and

```
which ftpput
```

returns

```
/system/xbin/ftpput
```